# NSMutableArray always initiates on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, nsmutablearray

I have declared an array in viewcontroller.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

In viewcontroller.m I put this code inside the implementation of the controller:

```
@synthesize array = _array;
```

In viewDidLoad-method I have this at the beginning:

```
if (_array == nil){
    NSLog(@"arr was null");
    _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

After the code above, I add an object to the mutable array this way:

```
[_array addObject:@"1"];
```

However, when I go from a controller to another in the simulator, the _array is always nil which allocate the array from scratch and all the old values disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Updated:
Im not using any navigation controller. Im using modal push. In ctrl2 I have override the method prepareForSegue putting this relevant code:

```
ViewController1 *ctrl1 = segue.destinationViewController;
ctrl1.anothervar = 3;
```

The real "redirection" to ctrl1 is done inside the method "tableView" in ctrl2 (when a use select an option). The code looks like this:
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"select_game_to_ctrl1" sender:self];

The ctrl1 has been given the identifier "select_game_to_ctrl1" (through storyboard)

Comment: Please give more information about what you mean by going from one controller to another. Also, paste your viewDidLoad method so we can see if anything is wrong with it.

Comment: Then what are you doing?

Comment: Sorry. I deleted the comment. I have controller1 and controller2 in the storyboard. Clicking on a button on controller1 takes me to ctrl2 with help of performSegueWithIdentifier. Ctrl1 is the first view. In viewDidLoad, the first time I go to this controller, the array should be initialized. Then there is the button which takes me to ctrl2. From there I go back to ctrl1 with performSegueWithIdentifier. Im also using prepareForSegue in ctrl2. So I finally go back to ctrl1 and in viewDidLoad the array is initialized again.

Comment: Wait why you are using "From there I go back to ctrl1 with performSegueWithIdentifier" performSegueWithIdentifier when you are coming back since it is already managed by iOS

Comment: iEinstein I dont understand your question. In ctrl2 there is a table with options. I need, in ctrl2, understand which option was selected and then use an instance of ctrl1 to set a (another) variable in ctrl1. Is it wrong to use this? I dont understand.

Comment: So I think you should use delegate not performSegueWithIdentifier for both parent viewcontroller as well as for child view controller

Comment: You said: "The real "redirection" to ctrl1 is done inside the method "tableView" in ctrl2 (when a use select an option). The code looks like this: [self performSegueWithIdentifier..." That is very, very wrong. performSegue creates a new copy of the destination view controller which is different from the original, and does not contain the data of the first one. Now you have 2.

Comment: Using performSegueWithIdentifier to go back is like buying a new car every time you want to to somewhere. Every time you get in a new car you have to re-adjust the seats, set your radio presets, etc. Even though the new car is the same year, make, model, and color, it's a different car. Eventually you run out of space in your driveway, and you run out of money.

Comment: What kind of segue are you using to get from ctrl1 to ctrl2? You still haven't told us that.

Comment: I said it, Im using modal segue. I dont have a navigation controller. When I create a suegue in storyboard, the options are "push" or "modal" (there is another one, i dont remember, but i never used it). If I select "push" than xcode complains about the fact that i dont have a navigation controller. So I had all the time to use modal segue for all my controllers.

Comment: So don't use another segue to get from ctrl2 back to ctrl1. That is the root of your problem. Instead, use a call to `dismissViewController:animated:completion:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the way you are navigating.

If you go from VC Ctrl1 to ctrl2 with a segue, you should NOT return from ctrl2 back to Ctrl1 via another normal segue. What that does is to create a new, blank instance of Ctrl1 and add that on top of your other view controllers. Since you create a new instance of Ctrl1, its viewDidLoad method gets called, and it creates a new, different array. The other copy of Ctrl1 is still there also, covered by ctrl2 and the new instance of Ctrl1 you just created.

How to fix it depends on what kind of segue you're using. If you're going from Ctrl1 to ctrl2 with a push segue (managed by a navigation controller), you should set up the return from ctrl2 back to ctrl1 as a pop.

**If you've going from Ctrl1 to ctrl2 via a presentModalViewController call, then you want to go back using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.**

The third option is to set up an unwind segue, but that's not really needed/appropriate when you're simply returning directly to the view controller you just came from.

If you need more help then tell us what kind of segue you are using to get from Ctrl1 to ctrl2, and post your prepareForSegue method from Ctrl1.

EDIT: The solution to your problem is in bold above.

Comment: Ok, but Im NOT going from ctrl1 to ctrl2 with presentModalViewController. Im going from ctrl1 to ctrl2 with performSegueWithIdentifier. So you mean I need to change ctrl1 and go to ctrl2 with presentModalViewController? And when Im in ctrl2, I still need to set variables in ctrl1. Wont I have the same problem then?

Comment: Also, I see that presentModalViewController has been deprecated. Is this really the way to go? What I want is to go from 1 to 2. And then when Im in 2, I want to set a variable on controller1 and also go back to it. What is the ordinary way to do this?

Comment: Yes, `presentModalViewController:animated:` was deprecated 2 major releases ago, in 6.0. (Soon to be 3 major releases ago - once iOS 8 is released.) Since you didn't spell out the whole name of the method, I missed the fact that you were naming the deprecated one. You should be using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead of presentModalViewController. And the corresponding new method for dismissing a modal is `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

Comment: If you're going from ctrl1 to ctl2 with a modal segue, the system does a `presentViewController:animated:completion:` call on your behalf. The way to undo a modal segue is to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` from your button action.

Comment: I am getting annoyed now. **WHAT YOU ARE DOING NOW IS ABSOLUTELY WRONG. YOU NEED TO USE `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` INSTEAD.** Did you hear me (and everybody else who's telling you that) this time?